# Factorizing a probability distribution

Tags: probability, distributions

I am trying to read a paper on factor graphs and coming from a cs background I am a little lost on the following proposition.

Not all distributions can be factored into a product of clique potentials.

The example they cite is the uniform distribution over binary vectors with an even number of ones. Why can't that be factored as such?

To start, what does the uniform distribution over binary vectors with an even number of ones even look like? What conditional dependencies exist to even try and encode into a PGM?